# Dropdown reload page then retrieve value

Tags: php, javascript

Hello so far been trying to use this line of code my goal is to reload the page via 
select then the select gets the value so the page will reload with the said value so
i may be able to retrieve it.
Both of these are in 1 form.
This is where i should get my value to be used once reloaded.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" class="typed" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo @$get_display->student_id;?>">
```

And this is what I'm trying to use to reload the page at get the value above.

```
    <select name="lvl" onchange="window.location='search_enroll.php?id='$_GET['student_id']">
```

Any help is appreciated thank you.

this is how i retrieve i have a problem in my last statement it is suppose to retrieve 
the value once reloaded.

```
   if (!empty($_POST['searchstudent'])){
                $id = $_POST['searchstudent'];

            }else if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
                $id = $_GET['id'];
            }
            else {
                $id= $_GET['student_id'];
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a form, you can just submit the form on change:

```
onchange="document.yourForm.submit()"
```

All parameters will be available to your PHP script.

Comment: Will it still be available once reloaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? Your page will be completely reloaded, but you have your parameters in your PHP script.

Comment: Sorry.. "It" referring to the student_id value.

Comment: Like I said, you have the student_id as `$_GET['student_id']` in your PHP script (assuming you are using `GET` method)

Answer (score 1):

When you write

`<select name="lvl" onchange="window.location='search_enroll.php?id='$_GET['student_id']">`

You actually navigate to the same student_id that got you to the page.

What you want to do is ask "which student_id did the user select?" and use that in the next page load.

The HTML should look something like

```
<form action="search_enroll.php">
    <select name="id" onchange="submit()">
       <option> student_id_1 </option>
       <option> student_id_2 </option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

Let me know if there are any problems.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtGCU/) to simulate the reload. (it will show a 404 as 'search_enroll.php' does not exist but you can still see that the reload works. )

EDIT : adding "hidden" input field after I was explained the purpose of this select

In case you have 2 fields ( student_id , grade ) you should add a hidden input field to the form. The form should look something like this :

```
<form action="search_enroll.php">
        <input value="<?php echo $_GET['student_id']?>" type="hidden"/>
        <select name="grade" onchange="submit()">
           <option> student_id_1 </option>
           <option> student_id_2 </option>
            ...
        </select>
</form>
```

This will make sure the student_id which user selected before will pass on to another reload.

Comment: I am sorry you misunderstood, My select is poppulated with the students year levels example: nursery, grade 1 to highschool . . so the idea is once the user clicked 3rd year for example the select will get the student_id which is already shown then reload now retrieve the value so it may be used in my sql statement to select * where student_id = student_id and yearlevel= 3rd year

Comment: So the flow is : 
1. select grade (1st year, 2nd year ..)
2. show the correct student list for this year
3. select student and then submit?

Comment: 1.Search student view all details 2. can view history 3 for example he is 3rd year clicks on the select 2nd year shows his information during his 2nd year. The problem is once reload the page retrieves the students id# again

Comment: @AntonApuaEscalante - do you have a link to a demo or something? I will try to make a demo on JSFiddle and we will try to move from there.

Comment: Currently i cannot find a way to retrieve the value of student_id once reloaded. but once i figure this out i can do the view history.

Comment: please see my edit and let me know if I understood correctly this time.

Comment: Yes yes . . fully understand it now, but i think my problem now is retrieving it. Please check up top to view the code i edited it. the last else statement is suppose to be the one to retrieve once reloaded. sorry for being a burden.

Comment: try using $_REQUEST. It seems you are a bit confused if the form is submitted with $_GET or $_POST and $_REQUEST contains both

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use PHP in your `select` element, because that is populated when the page is generated (server response), but what you are trying to do is populate it when the request is sent to the server.

The easiest would be to simply submit your form with whatever values are present when that field changes, using `onchange="document.aForm.submit()"`. Your server side validation will need to be able to understand that this is a partial submission, and that error messages should not be displayed to the user.

---

In response to poster's questions:

You have the following chain of events:

1. Client requests form page.
2. Server sends response, `select` element is populated with `option` elements.
3. Client selects an `option` element of `select` element.
4. Client sends request to server including `option` selected (*somehow*).
5. Server sends response, with some form elements changed, and the `option` element selected by the client in last request pre-selected.

The server cannot pre-populate the `onchange` attribute of the `select` element at step 1 (and shouldn't at step 5, because the client may change their selection); the server doesn't know which option the client will choose until the client chooses at step 3 and sends that choice to the server at step 4.

The reason I, and others, suggest `submit()` instead of `window.location` is that for a form, a client may complete the fields in any order, or you may later add fields before the `select`, in which case it is desirable that those choices be kept. `submit` keeps those, if the PHP obtains all fields from the `POST` object when generating the form. If `window.location` is used, then everything that is not included in the `GET` request is lost.

If you do want to use `window.location`, then JavaScript must be used to obtain the value of the selected `option` for the path (something like `?id=document.aForm.selectElement.options[document.aForm.selectElement.selectedIndex]`).

Comment: I am sorry you misunderstood, My select is poppulated with the students year levels example: nursery, grade 1 to highschool . . so the idea is once the user clicked 3rd year for example the select will get the student_id which is already shown then reload now retrieve the value so it may be used in my sql statement to select * where student_id = student_id and yearlevel= 3rd year

Comment: Right. Your `option` elements will be generated by PHP, because they are known by the server when the initial response is generated. Your `select` element `window.location` value will be not be generated by PHP, because you do not know what the user selects until they select it. `window.location` must be set by JavaScript (reading the value of the selected element), or by JavaScript submitting the whole form, and PHP getting that value from the Request/POST object. Submitting is way more user friendly than window.location.

Comment: I'm not that good, from what i understand you're suggesting the post method right? by using the select as the trigger?

Comment: Edited answer to explain in greater why the method being used now isn't working.